# Jitterbit upserting large csv tab-delimited file

Tags: java, salesforce, jitterbit

I have a problem with upserting csv file data using jitterbit, into a salesforce instance. I am going to provide as much information as I can here, but if there is anything else the experts would like to know, please ask me to provide.

I am not sure what to do to resolve this. I would appreciate some suggestions. Thank you very much.

**The error in jitterbit, when uploading csv**, is:

> Failure to deploy - "The file "tran9015s.jtr" does not exist. Looked for it here: "1503/1495/jtr/tran9015s.jtr". [GENERIC_EXCEPTION_OTHER]"`
>
> This is quite a large file (>400 MB),  which is in csv format, tab
>   delimited. I am using jitterbit 6.0.4.3. Operating system: Mac OS X
>   Maverick (with all relevant updates up-to-date) java : version 7
>   update 45

I had installed the jitterbit cloud data loader client, just today.
I am trying upload the contents of the csv file into my company's salesforce instance.
I had logged into jitterbit, chose new upsert, and then selected the appropriate salesforce object. 
I then selected an external ID field.
Then I selected the file to upsert.
In the preview pane which followed, I had made sure that is the right file I would like to upload.
Then I chose file type delimited file, with header. It is a tab delimited file, so I added \t as delimiter.
I skipped the scheduling options, maintaining it as "none", and chose "Map and Finish"

After linking all the approipriate fields, I then clicked on "Finish" and then "Run Upsert"

Then as it is "deploying project data", error occurs.

I have checked my java version, to make sure it is up to date. 
I have uninstalled and reinstalled Java, and uninstalled and reinstalled jitterbit - still not fixed.
restarting PC did not fix the problem.

I have a Microsoft 7 machine at work, and it also gives me the same error.
Googling has not been helpful, as no results could be found.

From the entire error message below, it might be that there is something wrong with Java, but I am not sure, and would appreciate some opinion and suggestion.

Thank you very much.

---

The entire error message is below:

> > java.lang.Exception: The file "tran9015s.jtr" does not exist. Looked for it here: "1503/1495/jtr/tran9015s.jtr". [GENERIC_EXCEPTION_OTHER]
> >
> > Client version: 6.0.4.3
> >     Client platform: Mac OS X - Java 1.7.0_25
> >
> > org.jitterbit.integration.client.server.IntegrationServerException: java.lang.Exception: The file "tran9015s.jtr" does not exist. Looked for it here: "1503/1495/jtr/tran9015s.jtr". [GENERIC_EXCEPTION_OTHER]
> >         at org.jitterbit.integration.client.server.webservice.RestServiceConfiguration.convertErrorResponseToException(RestServiceConfiguration.java:183)
> >         at org.jitterbit.integration.client.server.webservice.RestServiceConfiguration.rethrowFailure(RestServiceConfiguration.java:176)
> >         at com.jitterbit.integration.server.api.ws.agent.SyncAgentRestApi$Worker.callServer(SyncAgentRestApi.java:71)
> >         at com.jitterbit.integration.server.api.ws.agent.SyncAgentRestApi$Worker.syncAgent(SyncAgentRestApi.java:55)
> >         at com.jitterbit.integration.server.api.ws.agent.SyncAgentRestApi.syncAgent(SyncAgentRestApi.java:37)
> >         at com.jitterbit.integration.server.api.ws.deploy.DeployWorker.syncAgent(DeployWorker.java:264)
> >         at com.jitterbit.integration.server.api.ws.deploy.DeployWorker.sendToServer(DeployWorker.java:149)
> >         at com.jitterbit.integration.server.api.ws.deploy.DeployWorker.run(DeployWorker.java:98)
> >         at com.jitterbit.integration.server.api.ws.deploy.ProjectDeployerWsImpl.deployProject(ProjectDeployerWsImpl.java:51)
> >         at org.jitterbit.integration.client.project.deploy.DeployManager.sendDataToServer(DeployManager.java:134)
> >         at org.jitterbit.integration.client.project.deploy.DeployManager.deploy(DeployManager.java:87)
> >         at org.jitterbit.integration.client.ui.deploy.DeployJob.runImpl(DeployJob.java:40)
> >         at org.jitterbit.application.ui.job.UiJob.callRunImpl(UiJob.java:521)
> >         at org.jitterbit.application.ui.job.UiJob.run(UiJob.java:478)
> >         at org.jitterbit.application.ui.job.DefaultJobManager$UiJobWrapper.run(DefaultJobManager.java:205)
> >         at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:471)
> >         at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(FutureTask.java:334)
> >         at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:166)
> >         at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
> >         at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
> >         at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:724)